# JavaScript function to open modal dialog in Spring application

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I'm completely new to JavaScript. Can someone please explain what each line in this function does?

```
function openPoolModal(id){

console.log("I've been called");

$.ajax({
    url: "/" + id,
success: function(data){
    $("#PoolModalHolder").html(data);
    $("#PoolModal").modal("show");
}
});
}
```

I work with Spring & Thymeleaf and what I understand so far is that controller method is called via url. Controller method generates `data` and then what?

Here's the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping("/{id}")
public String getNetworkInfo(Model model, @PathVariable String id){

    model.addAttribute("poolHashrate", netService.getPoolHashrate(new Long(id)));

    return "networkDetails :: modalContents";
}
```

It also returns a part of .html fragment through Thymeleaf `th:fragment` attribute. I'm using https://qtzar.com/2017/03/24/ajax-and-thymeleaf-for-modal-dialogs/ tutorial, but I don't get the `PoolModalHolder` part.

Comment: ... and then returns it to the JavaScript caller which passes it to the `success` function.

Comment: You seem to understand it correctly, why are you unsure?

Comment: I don't get what this does: `$("#PoolModalHolder").html(data);`. Is `PoolModalHolder` an empty div? Where to put that div?

Comment: See: http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2
It simply sets HTML contents of the `PoolModalHolder` element.

Comment: How would we know if it is an empty `div` and where you should put it?

Answer (score 1):

to understand that code, you need to look for the th:fragment  **modalContents**, it should be in the file **networkDetails**.

```
model.addAttribute("poolHashrate", netService.getPoolHashrate(new Long(id)));

return "networkDetails :: modalContents";
```

The controller gets the "poolHashrate" object, then it's parsed through Thymeleaf on the fragment **modalContents** and an html code is generated.

The ajax code, receives that Html code and sets it as content of PoolModalHolder.